# Angular change Route but keep navigation as is

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular is built for Single Page Applications, so it should be possible to change the route but only have certain elements in the browser window changed, right?

For example I have a simple page with a main navigation component and a content area component.

Would it be possible to navigate to a different route and keep the main navigation component untouched?

Currently, when I do navigate to a different route, the main navigation component is always reloaded (OnInit is fired).

Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem you have embedded the main navigation component into another components that is assigned to different route. What I can suggest is If you have a shared navigation for every page, keep it in the app.component with the same level with router-outlet. Just like the [official example from Angular team](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt6/eplnkr.html).

So when you change the route, it will only affect the router-outlet. Your main-navigation will be init only one time.

*main-navigation.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main-navigation',
  template: `
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
      <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
    </nav>
  `
})

export class MainNavigationComponent {

}
```

*app.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <main-navigation></main-navigation>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```